# How to adjust the volume balance to the left and right separately in android?

Tags: java, android

I am having a problem, I have to handle the sound balance on the left and right earphones, describe in detail as follows:

-I have a slider the default position is in the middle, the default volume will be equal to the device's volume.

-When I drag the slider to the left, the right earphone will gradually become smaller until there is no more hearing and the left ear volume remains the same.

-Similar to the pull to the right, the left small until you can not hear anymore.
I don't know how to handle it so I hope everyone helps me.
[image]